# Powershell Switch - Multiple Clauses

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I'm creating a script that will be updating an Excel spreadsheet depending on conditions.

This is what I currently have:

```
if ($endIRs -ne $null) {
$endIRs | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $classification = $_.Classification
        $priority = $_.Priority
        $title = $_.Title 
        $id = $_.Id

        switch ($classification) {
            {($_ -eq 'Reports') -and ($priority -eq '1')} {
            $GeAppsReportSheet.Cells.Item(8,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            $GeAppsReportSheet.Cells.Item(8,2) = 'RED'
            }
            #more switch statements to go here
        }
     catch {#catch tickets with $classification not listed}
    }
}
```

The `$endIRs` at the start holds a series of high priority 'incidents' that have been logged in the last 12 hours. If there is none, everything will be 'GREEN' which is set by default.

What I am trying to achieve with the `switch` statement is `if (($classification -eq 'Reports') -and ($priority -eq '1')) {'change the cell colour and text'}` which I can do on its own, but I need it to check if the priority is "1" or "2" and do something different against the "Reports" classification cell in the spreadsheet.

Can you do an `if` statement within the `switch` statement, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$true` as the `switch` condition and put the checks as scriptblock values:

```
switch ($true) {
    {($classification -eq 'Reports') -and ($priority -eq '1')} {
        ...
    }
    # ...
    # more switch statements to go here
    # ...
    default {
        ...
    }
}
```

I never really liked this approach, though. Always looked like an ugly hack to me. I'd prefer a `if..elseif..else` control structure:

```
if ($classification -eq 'Reports' -and $priority -eq '1') {
    ...
} elseif (...) {
    ...
} elseif (...) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** Of course you can also use a "regular" `switch` statement and nest other conditionals in the action scriptblocks:

```
switch ($classification) {
    'Reports' {
        if ($priority -eq '1') {
            ...
        } elseif ($priority -eq '2') {
            ...
        }
    }
    # ...
    # more switch statements to go here
    # ...
    default {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation Matt.

@Ansgar - my thoughts were something along the lines of:

`switch ($classification) {
    'Reports' {if ($priority -eq '1') {colour cell RED} elseif ($priority -eq '2') {colour cell AMBER}}
}`
 - that sort of thing, if that makes sense?

Comment: @RossLyons That's certainly an option. See updated answer.